# jQuery select onChange update input field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, input

I have multiple sets of `select` and `input`s in one form and I need to update each input based on the selected value. Update the price in the input field based on the select dropdown.

The drop-down carries a value and a data attribute. The value is the quantity, and the data-attr is the price.

So when you select `<1>` from the drop-down, the input will change to `<1> *` its data-attribute.

I don't want to use ID's or classes or names to get current onChange.

// jQuery onChange this particular {select_drop_down}

```
<select class="select">
    <option value="1" data-price="2.99">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="2.99">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="2.99">3</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="2.99">4</option>
</select>
```

// update this input's value to the selected:index * data-price.
// new value: if option value=2 is selected, change input[type=text] to the new value.

```
<input type="text" value="2.99">
```

// same goes for the next {select_drop_down}

```
<select class="select">
    <option value="1" data-price="1.99">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="1.99">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="1.99">3</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="1.99">4</option>
</select>
```

```
<input type="text" value="1.99">
```

So this is what I have so far:

```
$(".select").change(function () {
    newPrice = 2.99; // I NEED HERE THE CURRENT data-price value;
    $(".one option:selected").each(function () {
        Price = newPrice*$(".unit").val();
    });
    $(this).nextAll('input').first().focus().val(Price.toFixed(2))
});
```

this works but only for the first drop-down, not the second.

Comment: `let newPrice = $("option:selected", this).data("price");`

Answer (score 5):

**Within the event `change` use the following to get the current selected option:**

```
var newPrice = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
```

The following code snippet just prints the selected value and set the `newPrice` to the next `input` field using `$(this).next('input').focus().val(newPrice);`.

**Now you can do any logic with that value.**

```js
$(".select").change(function () {
    newPrice = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
    console.log(newPrice);
    /*
    $(".one option:selected").each(function () {
        Price = newPrice*$(".unit").val();
    });*/
    
    $(this).next('input').focus().val(newPrice);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
    <option value="1" data-price="1.99">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="2.99">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="3.99">3</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="4.99">4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="1.99">
```